# Decoding a PCX image in c# to display as bitmap

Tags: c#, decoder, pcx

I have been trying to create a decoder that will stream through a pcx file and display it on screen as a bitmap. I have managed to get the information from the image header by using a binary reader, but I have now reached the part that seems to take the least amount of code, yet is also the hardest: creating an array of pixels.

I understand that i may need to add two embeddded `for` loops to process the data. I have looked at some C and C++ examples, but struggle to understand them. I also need to get the array to display it. if you need more code then I will share it.

I have searched far and wide and read the spec, but I don't know how to approach this. If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful.

Regards.

Comment: What sort of PCX files are you trying to read? Everything, or are you able to skip planes/palettes? It's not too hard in the abstract case. Create a Color[,] array to hold the actual pixel data, then loop through rows looping through columns to load individual planes/pixels.

Comment: I thought when that meteorite wiped out the dinosaurs all PCX files were gone too.

Comment: I don't mind just 8-bit images and i wasn't sure whether the palette was essential. Will your method work for other formats though?

Answer (score 0):

The .NET does not support PCX images natively, you have two choices. Read the specification and decode the image by yourself or use some library.

As suggested on [bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/790554-how-load-pcx-images-into-system-drawing-bitmap) you can use [Dot Net Fireball](http://dotnetfireball.codeplex.com/) (a [Free Image](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) wrapper) and load the image like this:

```
Fireball.Drawing.FreeImage freeImage = new FreeImage(@"c:\test.pcx");
Image image = freeImage.GetBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://magick.codeplex.com/

a nice wrapper working with http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/

easy to setup and get going, see samples at the bottom of the page here: 
http://magick.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: The link does not exist anymore:
http://magick.codeplex.com/